# gdb terminated while debugging qmake

Tags: qt, gdb, qt-creator, qmake

I'm debugging qmake in Qt Creator using Debug/Start Debugging/Start and Debug External Application... . It can break at the main function. I can step into the runQMake function. Then when I pressed F10 to step to the next line, gdb terminated. The messages in the debug log window when GDB terminated are:

```
 Step next requested...
<36-exec-next

dHANDLE GDB ERROR: The process was ended forcefully.
dProcess crashed
dGDB PROCESS FINISHED, status 1, exit code -1073741819
dNOTE: INFERIOR ILL
dState changed from InferiorRunRequested(7) to InferiorRunFailed(9)
dState changed from InferiorRunFailed(9) to InferiorStopOk(11)
dState changed from InferiorStopOk(11) to InferiorShutdownRequested(13)
dCALL: SHUTDOWN INFERIOR
dRUNNING NEEDS-STOP COMMAND kill 
dUNSAFE STATE FOR QUEUED COMMAND. EXECUTING IMMEDIATELY
<37kill
```

My compiler is Mingw, gdb version 8.1, Qt creator 5.12. Can anybody shed light on this problem? What could cause this problem? BTW, why cannot I see the first character("d") of every line of the log messages in the debug log window but the character is there when I copy and paste the messages here? Thanks!